# Perturbed polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, common-root

Out of curiosity, I'm wondering the solution of a perturbed problem in the form of :

$$p(z)+ap'(z)=0 $$

where $p(z)$ is a complex polynomial of order $N$, $'$ denotes the first derivative.

Additionally, the root of $p(z)$ and its derivative are known.

I wasn't able to find the solution of the general problem, if you have any idea, I'll be glad to hear them,

Comment: I suppose you are solving for $z$, rather than finding a polynomial that would satisfy the given equality (as there is obviously none due to degrees reasons apart from $p(z)\equiv 0$). And if so, I suppose the polynomial $p$ must be known (how else you want to express the solution?). In that case, LHS is just a polynomial in $z$, so it does not look too much different from finding roots of generic polynomial.

Comment: Is $a$ assumed to be small?

Comment: No, not too big either.
for $a$ small, we can assume that the solution are close to the root of $p$.
for $a$ big, the solution will be the solution of $p'$, plus an extra root equal to $a$ itself.